# Scaling an <a-sky> in aframe webvr

Tags: three.js, webvr, aframe

I'm working on a very simple a-frame webvr scene. I want to create an `<a-sphere>` that when interacted with will scale in size to mimic that of an `<a-sky>` component in that it will have a 360 photo material mapped to the inside.

Currently I have tried just starting with a small sky and scaling it up:

```
  <a-sky color="#000" scale="1 1 -1" radius="1">
    <a-animation attribute="scale" dur="10000" begin="500" to="1000 1000 -1"></a-animation>
  </a-sky>
```

I'm curious about how to best approach this, currently when I animate an increase in the scale the sphere expands but only fills up half of the world view and doesn't encapsulate the player. I believe this is because the initial radius is set to 1. Should I be scaling the radius instead of the scale? or should I write a custom sphere component and avoid using `<a-sky>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling the Z axis as well works for me `to="1000 1000 -1000"`

http://codepen.io/team/mozvr/pen/VazpEo?editors=100

A-Frame / https://aframe.io